# InfluxDB 1.8.3-1 as service on Windows10 using NSSM

Tags: shell, batch-file, windows-services, influxdb, nssm

hoping you can help me!
I'm writing a script to install some services in windows.
One of the services is InfluxDB. I need to use [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/).

But that's the problem.
If I use the nssm gui `nssm.exe install` and then set those parameters like following (and nothing else)

[image]

[image]

I'm able to run and connec to to instance

BUT

I need to install it from a `.bat` so I wrote few lines that run
`C:\nssm-2.24\nssm.exe install InfluxDB C:\influxdb-1.8.3-1\influxd.exe Start SERVICE_AUTO_START`.
It creates the service, but if I try to run it I get

[image]

and service goes to `Paused` state

I'm missing something?

Comment: Do you need to right-click on the script and select Run as Administrator?

Comment: I thought the same thing, but ad admin or not I get the same result!